# How can HTML page be populated with values from ini file

Tags: html, ini

On a webserver when I get a request to serve page index.html. How can I send certain values from an an ini file.
For example, index.html on server contains

```
 <input type="number" name="userChunkSize" value="1024">
```

Here, I don't want to send the value statically harcoded in index.html, but instead this value should be read from an ini file having the below lines, located at the same place in server as index.html

```
[index.html]
value=2048
```

After reading the ini file the final index.html returned should be

```
 <input type="number" name="userChunkSize" value="2048">
```

Any suggestions on how a better architecture can be done would also be greatly appreciated

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language.

Comment: My favorite language python :)

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unusual to use an .ini file for such a purpose.  Values that need to be generated dynamically should be created using a server side language such as php, asp, python, etc...  Then your 2048 could be loaded from a server side .ini file (not a great idea), or preferably from a database.

Comment: I agree with you ,and in addition, it's better to retrieve a JSON object instead of a .ini file. However, javascript have the `FileReader()` API that allows you to play with some text files,

Comment: Thanks, I am new to web development so don't know much about it. I was trying to keep my html simple by not emitting it from another language but I guess will have to switch to generating it dynamically